# Docker Daemon stop - Timeout for container defaults 10s

Tags: mysql, docker, influxdb

`docker stop` has a standard timeout of 10s ([Reference - Docker Stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)). This time window may be to short for the shutdown of mysql or influxdb to reach a consistent state on file system. If I stopped the container by hand, I would shut it down with `docker stop -t 60 mysql`. But that is not the default case. The containers are on auto restart and started and stopped with the docker daemon.

If I stop the docker daemon (e.g. on system reboot), the daemon will stop all running container with a timeout of 10 seconds, which can cause inconsistent dbs.

**Question:** Is there a way to set the global timeout for `docker stop` or the daemon stop?

Update 2016-05-03: Added [[Feature Request] Add config parameter to change stop timeout for containers or globally #22471](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22471) on github.

Answer (score 11):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Use the following config

```
--shutdown-timeout int            Set the default shutdown timeout (default 15)
```

or put it in docker daemon.json like below and restart docker daemon

```sh
tee /etc/docker/daemon.json <<-'EOF'
{
  "shutdown-timeout": 30,
  "live-restore": true
}
EOF
systemctl restart docker
systemctl status docker
```

Comment: This is not woking. "live-restore" option makes docker terminate without containers termination - that causes container kill just after daemon termination on host shutdown. Just "shutdown-timeout" is not working as expected - there is issue for that: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32357

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a global setting for this. It would be a nice feature, and you should [submit an issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues) to suggest it, and if you have time submit a pull request to implement.